# Como puedo mover box al pasar el mouse automaticamente

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

¿tengo un container padre donde contiene una bola, dicha bola quiero que se desplaze en cualquier coordenada o dirección dentro del contenedor padre? No se como aplicar este efecto estuve buscando mucho en internet pero algunos explicaciones son muy tecnicas y no sé entender bien, si alguien me puede resolver este problema de forma amena T.T se lo estaria agradeciendo. Saludos

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 1px solid;
   position: relative;
   margin: 20px auto;
}

.container #circle {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border-radius: 50px;
   background: red;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title> 
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="circle"></div>
  </div>
</body>

<script>
  const content = document.getElementById('box');
 
  box.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
    //mover box = x
    //mover box = Y
  });

 
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo se va a mover? Si quieres que siga al cursor, entonces el evento debe ser `mousemove`, porque `mouseenter` solo lo hará la primera vez que el cursor se posiciona dentro del contenedor. Usa las propiedades del evento `e.offsetY` para top y `e.offsetX` para left. Haz tus pruebas y, si todavía tienes dudas, edita la pregunta para agregar lo que intentaste y explicar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Para esto debes agregar o quitar clases de css y utilizar el transform o animation para mover el objeto: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate()

```js
  var circuloRojo = document.getElementById('circle');
  circuloRojo.addEventListener('mouseenter', (e) => {
    circuloRojo.classList.remove("circle");
     circuloRojo.classList.add("moved");
  });
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   border: 1px solid;
   position: relative;
   margin: 20px auto;
}

.container #circle {
   width: 50px;
   height: 50px;
   border-radius: 50px;
   background: red;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.moved {
  transform: translate(20px); 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title> 
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
   <div id="circle" class="circulo"></div>
  </div>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: Hola, quiero hacer esto mismo en jquery pero solo con javascript puro. https://es.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/jquery-example-mousemove-event/4920886418341888

Comment: ??No entendi con vanilla o con jquery es que quiere hacerlo?

Comment: Gracias igual yo lo resolvi con vanilla javascript :)